# Getting words from a file Inputs

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am trying to take in words from a file input that only contains strings and store each word separately into a single array (`ArrayList` is not allowed).

My code below takes in the file input, but takes it in as one chunk. For example, if the file input was "ONE TWO THREE" I want each word to have its own index in the array (`array[0] = "ONE"`, `array[1]="TWO"` and `array[2]="THREE"`) but my code below just takes the sentence and puts it all in `array[0] = "ONE TWO THREE"`. How can I fix this?

```
int i = 0;
String wd = "";
while (in.hasNextLine() ) {                
    wd = in.nextLine()  ;
    array[i] = wd;
    i++; 
    System.out.println("wd");
}
```

Comment: If you don't know the exact number of words at first, I would recommend you using a List instead of an array : `list.add(wd);`

Comment: @Rob ` (no arraylist aloud)` :)

Comment: @PremGenError Woops right, I didn't read that sorry. But all Lists are not ArrayLists of course.

Comment: as a tag-on to Rob, if you must return as an array, you can do List.toArray().

@PremGenError a list is not the same as an arraylist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats happens because you a reading LINES from the file. You can do something like this:

```
String array[]=in.nextLine().split(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

> f the file input was " ONE TWO THREE" i want each word to have its own
>   space in the array so array[0] = ONE, array[1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)=TWO and array[2]=THREE

Use [**String#split(delim)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) with white space as delimiter.

```
String fileInput = "ONE TWO THREE";
String[] array = filrInput.split("\\s");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the line

```
array[i] = wd; // since wd is the whole line, this puts lines in the array
```

you want to split the line you read in and put the split items in your array.

```
String[] items = wd.split("\\s+"); // splits on any whitespace
for (String item : items) { // iterate through the items and shove them in the array
    array[i] = item;
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would set the delimiter to space " " then use .next().

```
in.useDelimiter(" ");
while(in.hasNext()){
    wd = in.next();
    //wd will be one word
}
```